# React / Fetch Error: Objects are not valid error

Tags: reactjs, fetch

This component fetches one data record, and I'm trying to pass this data record to a display component. I call a 'fetchProduct' method, assign the result to a const, but then get the 'Error: Objects are not valid.........' message.

The solution is really close, but I'm stuck and need some help to get there. Thank you for your attention.

**Here is the code:**

```
import ProductDetailDisplay from '../../components/product/ProductDetailDisplay'

export default async function ProductDetail ( props ) {
    let { productId } = props

    async function fetchProduct(productId) {
        // fetch call that works
    }

    // this gets the right data, but now there's Object are not valid... error
    let productData = await fetchProduct(productId) 
    console.log('productData ', productData) 

    return <h3>test message</h3>

    // return <ProductDetailDisplay data={productData} handleAddToCart={ handleAddToCart }/>
}
```

Comment: This probably has something to do with the render/return of the ProductDetailDisplay component, maybe trying to directly render the contents of `data`? Do you get a full error message ("Objects are not valid as a React child(found: Object with keys[...]", perhaps)? Can you provide that and a pared down version of your ProductDetailDisplay component?

Comment: Hi toki- the error happens even if the ProductDetailDisplay component is commented out, and a test message is returned in its place. I've edited the code example to show this.

Comment: Can you add a demo of `fetchProduct` output?

Comment: [`async` functions **always** return a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value), that is how they are able to be asynchronous. Since you are defining your React component `ProductDetail` as async, it will return a Promise, which React doesn't know how to render. You want to use a regular function instead, and perform your fetch within a [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

Comment: thank you everyone for your responses. This works now.

the solution was to assign the productData variable as state (productData, setProductData). this removes all of the issues with Promises.

As I work with React, I try to push it in directions it may not want to go. Now I know for certain how to work with async stuff. useEffect -> useState; it is now much more clear to me how these work.

Thank you for your adivices and attention.